# BIOS int 13H, AH=02 (to read floppy) and the stack segment

Tags: x86-16, stack-memory, bios, memory-segmentation

If I don't initial stack segments, what will happen?

Will when some case cause reading errors?

Answer (score 2):

Your stack segment register better have a valid value when you invoke a software interrupt, (or make any call,) because the `int` (or `call`) instruction needs a valid stack in which to store the return address to your code.  Also, the invoked subroutine usually expects that there is a valid stack in which it can `push` some registers in order to do its job.

As a matter of fact, your stack segment register better have a valid value at all times, otherwise everything will crash and burn as soon as the first periodic interrupt occurs.

Comment: Thank you~I understand the importance of initialing stack segment. And what is 'first periodic interrupt occurs'?

Comment: If I don't initial stack segment,how large of stack I can use? How large I can set for stack segment?

Comment: The IBM PC has a Periodic Interrupt Controller chip which generates hardware interrupts at regular intervals. (About 50 times a second.) When one of these interrupts occurs, there must be a valid stack, or else you have a crash. That's why we always disable interrupts (`cli`) before we manipulate the stack segment register or the stack pointer register and re-enable them afterwards (`sti`).

Comment: In order to set up a stack, you have to initialize the stack segment register and the stack pointer register.  But normally a stack is already set up for you by the operating system when your program starts running, so generally you should not have to set up your own stack, meaning that you should not need to worry about this whole issue at all.

Comment: The stack should be large enough to contain whatever variables you allocate in it, plus a few hundred bytes for interrupts that may occur while your program runs. If I had to set up a stack, I would give it a couple of kilobytes.

Comment: I use bochsdbg to break at 0x7c00. I found that SS=0 and esp=0xffd6. Does it says that after BIOS, I can use a stack that size equal 0xffd6 ?